# Getting random number divisible by 16

Tags: javascript

In math how do I obtain the closest number of a number that is divisible by 16?

For example I get the random number 100 and I want to turn that number (using a math function) into the closest number to 100 that is divisible by 16 (In this case its 96)

I'm trying to do this in JavaScript but if I knew the math formula for it I would easily do it in any language.

Thank you,
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function GetRandomNumberBetween(lo, hi) {
  return Math.floor(lo + Math.random() * (hi - lo));
}

Number.prototype.FindClosestNumberThatIsDivisibleBy = function(n) {
  return Math.round(this / n) * n; //simplify as per Guffa

  /* originally:
     var c = Math.ceil(n);
     var f = Math.floor(n);
     var m = num % n;
     var r = f * n;
     if (m > (n / 2))
       r = c * n;
     return r;
  */
};

var r = GetRandomNumberBetween(10, 100);
var c = r.FindClosestNumberThatIsDivisibleBy(16);
```

Comment: That works but I dont understand why you round up and down and if the rest is bigger than 8 you use the "upper round" to get the result

Comment: I need those two numbers to actually get the closest number to that random number that was generated.  Basically, if the remainder is higher than or equal to the half point (half of 16 is 8), then I'll use the ceiling instead of the floor and multiply that by 16 to get the closest number.

Comment: @user572420: He's doing that to get the same result that the `round` method returns. I'm not sure why the `round` method is avoided, though...

Answer (score 19):

Generate a random integer.  Multiply it by 16.

Comment: or shift it by 4 if speed is required: `myNum << 4`

Comment: @snjgm: Yes, although in a compiled language the compiler will make this optimisation for you (I don't know whether the Javascript interpreter does this sort of power reduction).  Also, I was assuming that 16 was just an example; perhaps in practice the OP could want any multiplier.

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants?

Comment: @Jimmy: I think it is (based on the question title).  The stuff about rounding is his/her current best solution, and is therefore a red herring.

Comment: I get a random number. Then I need to get the closest number to that random one that is divisible by 16.

Comment: Isn't this solution for generate a random integer and then multiply it by 16?  If you read the question, he is generating a random number and based on the random number generated, find the closest number to that random number that is divisible by 16... at least that's how I understand it...

Comment: @user572420: "Getting a random number divisible by 16"...  If that's not what you want, you ought to be a bit clearer!

Comment: I might not have been much clear on the title but I think Ive explained myself correctly on the text and with the example I gave

Answer (score 15):

Divide by 16, round, and multiply by 16:

```
n = Math.round(n / 16) * 16;
```

Comment: lol... my brain must not be working... yeah Math.round will do and definitely much simpler :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function closest(n) {
  var r = 0, ans = 0;

  r = n % 16

  if r < 8 {
    ans = n - r
  } else {
    ans = n + (16 - r)
  }

  return ans;
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your "less that 8 = subtraction, more/equal than/to 8 = addition", it works if its always subtraction but does not if I do an addition

Comment: Oops, sorry, it's my fault. Update now.

Comment: Yes, its working now If I always subtract it works as well. What is the difference? Is it supposed to be more accurate, I mean, if the rest is bigger than 8 (half) it gets to the higgest number instead of using always the lowest?

Comment: As your question stated, you want the closest number, right? Consider the case for 110, the remainder r = 14, so `110 - 14 = 96`, `110+(16-14) = 112`. 112 is closer than 96, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I understand your question. You're given a number A, and you have to find a number B that is the closest possible multiple of 16 to A.

1. Take the number given, "A" and divide it by 16
2. Round the answer from previous step to the nearest whole number
3. multiply the answer from previous step by 16

there's the pseudocode, hope it's what you're looking for ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A general JS solution

```
var divisor = 16;

var lower = 0;
var upper = 100;    

var randDivisible = (Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper-lower))+lower)*divisor;
alert(randDivisible);
```